# Select only changed rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, postgresql

my rows looks like this:

```
1
0 ----> Change! This row is of interest
1 ----> Change again.
1
1
1
1
1
0 ----> Change.
1 ----> Change.
```

There can be a million zeros before a new 1 and I only want the changes (the rows marked with Change). This would bring me a result with about 10 million rows less. We support SQLServer and PostGresSQL. It's ordered by a timestamp column. A 0 is system offline flag and 1 system online. A service reports this information at intervals and timestamps it.

Any ideas?
Edit:
There's plenty of other columns one is a timestamp column that determines the order. A 0 is system offline flag and 1 system online. A service reports this information at intervals and timestamps it.

Cheers

Comment: any other columns in your table?

Comment: Yes many, forgot to mention it sorry.

Comment: so what are the other columns? Is there a unique ID? How do you know when a change happened (i.e. how is the data ordered). We need much more info?

Comment: Please elaborate your question

Comment: How do you know what is the order that should be taken into account when checking for changes? For example, assuming your "interesting" column is named "x", then if you'd have "order by x" then you would have just one change (from 0 to 1, once).

Comment: How do you know that this particular row is for change?

Comment: Very good question. It's ordered by a timestamp column. A 0 is system offline flag and 1 system online. A service reports this information at intervals and timestamps it.

Comment: So in my question i use order by timestamp and it works except I can't handle all the rows

Answer (score 6):

OK. So based on a comment we know there is timestamp column. Let's assume this is named "event_when", and the 0/1 column is named "status".

So, we can:

```
with x as (
    select
        *,
        lag(status) over (order by event_when) is distinct from status as interesting
    from table
)
select * from x where interesting;
```

Comment: +1 interesting query, I suppose it's PostgreSQL compatible and not SQL Server?

Comment: I have no idea about SQL Server. Don't have it, don't have windows, can't test. But - window functions and CTEs are not magical, and I would guess that any respectable database should have them.

Comment: Based on answer from Alejandro Colorado, it looks that SQL Server does have window functions - at least rank()

Comment: SQL Server introduces LEAD and LAG: http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2011/11/15/sql-server-introduction-to-lead-and-lag-analytic-functions-introduced-in-sql-server-2012/

Comment: SQL Server does have windows function but i'm pretty sure that syntax `is distinct from status` will not work, can't test right now :(

Comment: you will usually get away with `<>` instead of `is distinct from`

Comment: This code wont work in SQL Server, even changing `is distinct from` with `<>`. BTW, @RomanPekar's modified answer will.

Answer (score 2):

If you have ID's, and they are sequential, you can try something like:

```
SELECT table1.* FROM table table1, table table2 
WHERE table1.id = table2.id- 1
AND table1.value != table2.value
```

It's a little hard to say without seeing the rest of your structure, but in the above case, `value` is the column that contains the `0` or `1` and `id` is the primary key.  If you don't have an id column, or they are not incremental, then you may need to specify a more complex selector, or include more of your schema here.

Comment: I don't have ID's and I can't impact the database design.

Comment: @KarlKildén Then how are you ordering the rows?

Comment: This solution has a problem which would bite if there were gaps in ids.

Comment: You are assuming id is sequential and there have not been deleted rows.

Comment: @AlejandroColorado and depesz, yes, I am, those are good points.  However, I'm mostly shooting for the "right track" since we don't know any more of the schema.

Answer (score 0):

we have to know how to find previous row, but the general solution would be (I'm supposing that your rows have column Date and it's unique)

```
select *
from temp as t1
    outer apply
    (
        select top 1 *
        from temp as t2
        where t2.Date < t1.Date /* or you columns */
        order by t2.Date desc /* or you columns */
    )
where t2.value <> t1.value
```

**EDIT:** As I'm usually work on 2008 R2 SQL Server, I forgot about LAG and LEAD functions. So, based on @depesz answer for PostgreSQL, here's SQL Server version:

```
with CTE_temp as (
    select
        *,
        lag([State]) over (order by [Time]) as State_Previous
    from temp
)
select *
from CTE_temp
where State_Previous <> [State]
```

[**SQL FIDDLE EXAMPLE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/8313f/7)

Comment: Well, if there is proper ordering possible, then there are better solutions. but so far, we don't know of any such ordering.

Comment: if by proper ordering you mean sequential data, than yes, it's possible

Comment: No, by proper ordering I mean - there is a way to sort the data. At the time of my comment, original question did not contain any information about "order by column".

Answer (score -1):

**Option #1**: Using MS SQL SERVER 2008

Ordering with the timestamp, we can use the `rank()` function and a temporary table. A CTE and a table variable can also be used. Performance is a tricky part, so I would suggest testing the three options if this is going to be repeated in the future. I'll show two examples:

- TEMPORARY TABLE ([try it in SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/269af/5)):

  ```
  select  rank() OVER (ORDER BY order_timestamp) as 'Rank', status into temp1 from temp

  select t1.status as status, case when t1.status - t2.status = 0 then 'not changed' else 'changed' end as changed
  from temp1 t1, temp1 t2 
  where t1.Rank = t2.Rank + 1

  drop table temp1
  ```
- CTE ([try it in SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/269af/6)):

  ```
  with CTE_temp as (
      select rank() OVER (ORDER BY order_timestamp) as 'Rank', * 
      from temp
  )
  select t1.status as status, case when t1.status - t2.status = 0 then 'not changed' else 'changed' end as changed
  from CTE_temp t1, CTE_temp t2 
  where t1.Rank = t2.Rank + 1
  ```

**Option #2**: Using MS SQL SERVER 2012

MS SQL SERVER 2012 introduced `lead` and `lag` (http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2011/11/15/sql-server-introduction-to-lead-and-lag-analytic-functions-introduced-in-sql-server-2012/).

In this case, option #1 is still valid, but you can also try @RomanPekar's solution.

**UPDATE:**

Based on @RomanPekar's comment (and someone's downvote), I have to say that a temporary table can perfectly perform better than a CTE and a table variable, especially when a large set of data is expected. The optimizer can use statistics from the temporary table to establish its query plan, and this can result in performance gains.

Likewise, depending on the use the OP wants to give the data afterwards (maybe more queries), the temporary table is still there, no new query has to be executed, and indexes can be used to improve performance in those cases.

BTW, hacking my answer and converting it to a CTE or a table variable is easy, so I would suggest the OP to test performance for the three cases if this is an operation he will repeat in the future.

Comment: not sure it's good solution to put 10 million rows into new table